# Missing Range header in AspNetCore

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

I'm missing the Range header, when the browser makes a http request.

These are the headers sent by the browser:

```
GET /Shared/Files/DownloadFile/856 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0
Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://localhost:5001/Basic/Message/Details/611/
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: Session=0af9f0f2-3201-43a9-b7af-e9d91390b42a
```

I have my own implementation of `IActionResult`

```
public class PartialContentResult : IActionResult
{
    public PartialContentResult(int id, AzurePrivateStorage azure)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.azure = azure;
    }

    public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var headers = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers;

        // headers["Range"] always return StringValues.Empty
        var range = headers["Range"].ToString();
        // Why is Range always empty??
            
        var match = Regex.Match(range, @"^bytes=(\d*)-(\d*)");
        Task result;
        if (match.Success)
        {
            long? from = GetLongValue(match.Groups[1].Value);
            long? to = GetLongValue(match.Groups[2].Value);
            long? length = from - to;

            result = azure.Download(id, context, from, length, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        }
        else
        {
            result = azure.Download(id, context, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private long? GetLongValue(string value)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : (long?)Convert.ToInt64(value);
    }
}
```

`headers["Range"]` always return `StringValues.EmptyString` in `ExecuteResultAsync`.

The request is initialized from MVC. This is my controller.

```
[UserAuthorize]
[Area("Shared")]
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile([FromServices] AzurePrivateStorage azure, int id)
    {
        try
        {
            await CheckDownloadAccess(id);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedUserAccessException)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
        }
        return new PartialContentResult(id, azure);
    }

    [...]
}
```

I've tried both Kestrel and IIS Express, but the results are the same. The Range header is missing on the server.

I'm running .NET Core 3.1.4.

Comment: Missing from where? The request or the response?  `IActionResult` is used to generate the response. Where's the code that handle's the request?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've updated the original post, to include part of the controller.

Comment: I've tried setting up a simple project at video response. Here the Kestrel server does not give the Range header, but IIS Express does give the Range header. The problem exists in both .NET Core 3.1.4 and .NET Core 5.0.0-preview.7 (latest version).

Comment: If this really is a Kestrel problem you'll be able to verify it by returning a `File` result with `EnableRangeProcessing` set. You can either use a [File()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.1) overload that accepts `enableRangeProcessing` or set the property on the returned `FileResult` object explicitly. One way would be `return File(...){EnableRangeProcessing=true};`

Comment: I've setup a test case on github: https://github.com/hermandsen/RangeTest

With `EnableRangeProcessing` enabled, the Range header is not sent, when running Kestrel.